# Java Generic Method to enforce type invariance between parameter type and return type

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, interface

I have tried a number of different variations of the code below and cannot find any solution which doesn't rely on an unsafe cast or cause another other compiler warning. I am confident the goal is possible, but maybe not?

To put it simply, the goal is that I have derived types which are related to each other and have invariant relationship, **which can be enforced by a generic method.**

`AlphaTask` always returns `AlphaTaskResult`.
`AlphaTask` is a concrete implementation of `ITask<T>`, where `T` is `String`.
`AlphaTaskResult` extends the base class of `TaskResult<T>`, where again `T` is `String`.

Everything checks out until it comes to writing a generic method which take any `Task` and get back the corresponding `TaskResult` type.

The error is:

```
Required type: List<U>
Provided:      List<TaskResult<T>>
no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that TaskResult<T> conforms to U inference variable T has incompatible bounds: equality constraints: U lower bounds: TaskResult<T>
```

```java
package com.adobe.panpipe;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


interface ITask<T>{
    TaskResult<T> make();
}

class TaskResult<T>{
    T value;
}

class AlphaTaskResult extends TaskResult<String> {
    AlphaTaskResult(String value){
        this.value = value;
    }
}

class BetaTaskResult extends TaskResult<Integer> {
    BetaTaskResult(Integer value){
        this.value = value;
    }
}

class AlphaTask implements ITask<String> {
    public AlphaTaskResult make(){
        return new AlphaTaskResult("alphaTask");
    }
}

class BetaTask implements ITask<Integer> {
    public BetaTaskResult make(){
        return new BetaTaskResult(9001);
    }
}

public class Main <T>{

    public static <T, U extends TaskResult<T>, V extends ITask<T>> List<U> run(List<V> tasks){

        List<U> results =  tasks
                .stream()
                .map(ITask::make)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return results;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<AlphaTaskResult> alphaResults = run(Arrays.asList(new AlphaTask(), new AlphaTask()));
        List<BetaTaskResult> betaResults = run(Arrays.asList(new BetaTask(), new BetaTask()));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the type `R extends TaskResult<T>` of the result to the type `ITask` of the task. The following compiles just fine:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


interface ITask<T, R extends TaskResult<T>>{
    R make();
}

class TaskResult<T>{
    T value;
}

class AlphaTaskResult extends TaskResult<String> {
    AlphaTaskResult(String value){
        this.value = value;
    }
}

class BetaTaskResult extends TaskResult<Integer> {
    BetaTaskResult(Integer value){
        this.value = value;
    }
}

class AlphaTask implements ITask<String, AlphaTaskResult> {
    public AlphaTaskResult make(){
        return new AlphaTaskResult("alphaTask");
    }
}

class BetaTask implements ITask<Integer, BetaTaskResult> {
    public BetaTaskResult make(){
        return new BetaTaskResult(9001);
    }
}

public class Main <T>{

    public static <T, R extends TaskResult<T>> List<R> run(List<ITask<T, R>> tasks){

        List<R> results =  tasks
                .stream()
                .map(ITask::make)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return results;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<AlphaTaskResult> alphaResults = run(Arrays.asList(new AlphaTask(), new AlphaTask()));
        List<BetaTaskResult> betaResults = run(Arrays.asList(new BetaTask(), new BetaTask()));

    }
}
```

The reason why your version does not compile is that the exact type of the result is not included in the type of the task, and since there are no type refinements in Java, there is nothing from which the type `U` could be inferred.

Comment: Accepting this answer as the most concise. I believed I tried this very straightforward implementation but hit some problem, but I must have done something subtly different. Kudos, thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

There is no connection between `ITask` and `TaskResult`. Sure, the task implementations override `make` with their respective return types, but this information can't be used in the declaration of the `run` method.

You can make the connection by adding an additional type parameter to `ITask`:

```
interface ITask<T, TResult extends TaskResult<T>>{
    TResult make();
}

class TaskResult<T>{
    T value;
}
```

Change the task implementations and `run` accordingly:

```
class AlphaTask implements ITask<String, AlphaTaskResult> {
    public AlphaTaskResult make(){
        return new AlphaTaskResult("alphaTask");
    }
}

class BetaTask implements ITask<Integer, BetaTaskResult> {
    public BetaTaskResult make(){
        return new BetaTaskResult(9001);
    }
}

public class Main { // Main doesn't need a type parameter
    public static <T, U extends TaskResult<T>, V extends ITask<T, U>> List<U> run(List<V> tasks){

        List<U> results =  tasks
            .stream()
            .map(ITask::make)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return results;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<AlphaTaskResult> alphaResults = run(Arrays.asList(new AlphaTask(), new AlphaTask()));
        List<BetaTaskResult> betaResults = run(Arrays.asList(new BetaTask(), new BetaTask()));
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm upvoting this answer but not accepting it as the solution because it is correct and effectively equivalent to Andrey Tyukins but defines extra type parameter V to represent Task<T,R>, which seems fine but unnecessary. It seems just slightly less concise.  If there some other functional difference I missed let me know.